# Magento template question

Tags: templates, magento, configurable

I have a problem with Magento's configurable product template.

http://clientsupports.com/mind/index.php/clothing/bottoms/33.html

I would like to move color and size under the price $33.00. I tried to modify catalog.xml in layout directory. I tried to find a template file under catalog/product/view, but I can't find anything.

What files should I update??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Magento, the way to find out what template or block to edit is to 'enable template hints'.  This puts boxes around each block on a page, and notes what block and what template generate it.

You can enable template hints from the admin under System->Configuration->Developer->Debug.
Note that you'll have to choose a website scope on the upper left.  The option isn't available in the default scope.

One more note that may be helpful - If your site is live already, or other people are using it, there's an option there to limit the template hints to only your IP.

Comment: Wow...that is really really useful information. Thank you a lot!!